# Chrome autofill does not trigger validation. Standard autofill event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, google-chrome

I'm doing some client-side validation with https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/

It works fine unless the Chrome autofill is triggered, at which point the validation plugin does not recognize changes to the input values and does not trigger.

I am not allowed to use autocomplete="off" and I'm not sure that would prevent the autofill anyway.

Is there any way I can universally listen for browser autofill events?

Comment: As @A.Wolff said, this is a duplicate. That question is actually referenced from the Chromium page for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=352527. Some suggested workarounds are there, though it sounds like the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

As i can test it, `input` event is fired:

```
$('input').on('input',function(){
    console.log(this.value);
});
```